# the output of using np.empty_like in Python

Tags: python, numpy

While studying the `NumPy` package of `Python`, I tried the following code segment

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
v = np.array([1,0,1])
y = np.empty_like(x)
print(y)
for i in range(4):
   y[i,:] = x[i,:]+v
print "......."
print(y)
```

However, the first `print(y)` gives the output such as following, instead of all zero array. On the other side, the second `print(y)`generates the correct result as expected. I would like to know why.

```
[[        72          0          0]
 [         0       2676 1346720256]
 [1599357253 1950699087         10]
 [1346524499 1163154497  242503250]]
 .......
[[ 2  2  4]
 [ 5  5  7]
 [ 8  8 10]
 [11 11 13]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `zeros_like`. `empty_like` gives an array filled with who-knows-what, so it doesn't have to spend time filling it with zeros.